# Exception when selecting specific columns using Hibernate and Spring Data JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table that has a bytea column (named 'pdf') and I don't want to always select it, specially when I'm returning a list from the database, due to performance issues.

I use native queries with spring data inside the repository to solve these types of situations before (when I used eclipselink), but with Hibernate, if I don't write all the columns in the query, it throws an exception.

For test purposes, I'm trying to select only the *id* from the User and I still get the exception.

Example: "SELET user.id FROM user WHERE user.id = '1'"

It throws an exception saying that it did not find *name* in the ResultSet, if I put *name* in the SQL, it then says *age* was not found and so on, until I have to write all the columns in the SQL.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**What I have tried already**:

- Updating/Downgrading Hibernate and Spring Data with no luck.
- Creating a new entity with only the columns I need, works, but it's a messy solution for me.

Maybe the problem is the combination of the frameworks I use and the way I use them, if someone wants, I could try to upload my whole project structure.

---

**My code**:
*Entity*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "portal")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "pdf")
private byte[] pdf;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "age")
private Integer age;

public User() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public byte[] getPdf() {
    return pdf;
}

public void setPdf(byte[] pdf) {
    this.pdf = pdf;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}    

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Anexo)) {
        return false;
    }
    Anexo other = (Anexo) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "br.gov.to.secad.portal.domain.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

---

*Service*

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private IUserRepository userRepository;


public UserService() {
}


public User findOne() {
    return userRepository.findOneSQL();
}

}
```

---

*Repository*

```
public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Serializable>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

@Query(value = "SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.id = '1'", nativeQuery = true)
public User findOneSQL();

}
```

---

**The exception:**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name name was not found in this ResultSet.
```

---

**Solution**

The solution is using an array of Object when I want to select anything less than what I've mapped on my Entity class, thats the limitation of Hibernate that I now understand.

So basically, the method will return Object[] and then I can iterate each position and instantiate a new entity of User with these values.

Example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.id = '1'", nativeQuery = true)
public Object[] findOneSQL();
```

Comment: 1. why use a native query instead of a JPQL one? 2. Why use `= '1'` since the ID is supposed to be an integer? 3. Hw could a query that selects only user.id, which is an integer, return an object of type User?

Comment: I need to use native query because of the complexity that my final solution needs and we don't want to have the trouble to translate a dozen or so line native query SQL to JPQL

Comment: I used `= '1'` just as an example to try and select a single User

Comment: The query returns an object of type User because JPA will do the serialization. But again, the example I wrote was just to show that I get the exception with a simple query.

Comment: No, it won't. If you want to get a User, then use a JPQL query such as `select u from User where ...`. JPA can't magically construct a User with N fields just from a single integer. If you want to use that query, make it a JPQL query (there's no reason to use a native one): `select u.id from User u where ...`, and make the method return an Integer, not a User.

Comment: @JBNizet I have this native query working fine using eclipselink and the same setup. I get a list of _area_  as a result and not an Object

`SELECT a.id, a.titulo, a.descricao
    FROM siga_unicet.area as a`

Comment: @sbjavateam Still the same exception, saying that **name** was not found in the ResultSet

Comment: I think you have to list all the fields in your select, your select is not generating a name column only an id.

Comment: @xenoterracide Yes, hibernate wants me to list all the fields, but I know I can customize that and return only what I want, but it's not letting me with native queries, which I used to do before with Eclipselink with no problem

Comment: @WandyerSilva you can (and probably should) use a projection, that only has the fields you need.

Comment: or you could use eclipselink instead of hibernate...

Comment: @xenoterracide unfortunately, chaning to eclipselink is not an option for us

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.id = '1'", nativeQuery = true)
Integer findOneSQL();
```

Call the method like so

```
Integer user = userRepository.findOneSQL();
```

**Edit 1 :**

Since you are using native query you wont be able to use [`Projections`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) which is a great way of accessing only certain entity fields. There is a JIRA [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-980) which is still under investigation.

**Solution**

Return List from your repository like so

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user.id, user.name  FROM user WHERE user.id = '1'", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findOneSQL();
```

Iterate over the list of Objects and get your specific columns.

```
List<Object[]> userNative = userRepository.findOneSQL();
for (Object[] obj : userNative) {
    System.out.println("User id : " + obj[0]);
    System.out.println("User Name : " + obj[1]);
}
```

Comment: I actually want other columns from user, not just the `id`, so my result has to be the User entity. I want `id, name, age` but not `pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have tried returning my query to a Object[], it works fine, it's a little hassle to iterrate it and get the values I need, but it's a solution. What I want to know is, has nobody faced this issue before? Is everyone using Object[] when they want specific columns?

Comment: Please do post your reasons for down voting. Maybe I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, I know it is late but well there is a solution that I found elegant.

By the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) you can declare an interface and from here take the fields you want, in my case it has been something similar to this.

The interface to minimize the fields:

```
public interface CountryMinify {
   String getName();
   String getNameTranslation();
}
```

And my JpaRepository

```
public interface PlanetRepository extends JpaRepository<Planet, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select p.name_country as name, p.name_country_translation as nameTranslation from vm_planet p where gid = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    CountryMinify findByCode(String codeCountry);
}
```

Keep in mind that the columns should be called the same as gos getter. For example: column name_country -> AS name and the getter of the interface is getName()